# Bezier Handles Keep Radius and Symmetry but not length

Tags: javascript, bezier

I'm Having a Bezier Curve in Javascript built with a few bezier Curves.
I can move handles and they keep the symmetry. I'm doing that by first calculating
the distance between Handle and Point on Beziér. Then I compare the distances
of the two handles, calculate a multiplier and apply it to the not dragged
handle. This works for keeping Symmetry.

But I want to achieve that the length of the not dragged handle stays the same.

http://cl.ly/image/0c1z00131m2y (a little picture explaining what i mean).

The code, i currently use to calculate the movement is this:

```
    dx = Math.abs(drag.x - point.p[(draggedItemIndex)/2].x);
    dy = Math.abs(drag.y - point.p[(draggedItemIndex)/2].y);
    dx2 = Math.abs(point.cp[draggedItemIndex-1].x - point.p[draggedItemIndex/2].x);
    dy2 = Math.abs(point.cp[draggedItemIndex-1].y - point.p[draggedItemIndex/2].y);

    dxdx = dx2/dx;
    dydy = dy2/dy;

    point.cp[draggedItemIndex-1].x -= dragX*dxdx;
    point.cp[draggedItemIndex-1].y -= dragY*dydy;
```

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now doing it with ciruclar calculations.

```
    //Circle Center Point
                cx = point.p[(draggedItemIndex)/2].x;
                cy = point.p[(draggedItemIndex)/2].y;

                //Dragged Point Position (To Circle Origin)
                x1 = drag.x - cx;
                y1 = drag.y - cy;

                //Mirrored Point Position (To Circle Origin)
                x2 = point.cp[draggedItemIndex-1].x - cx;
                y2 = point.cp[draggedItemIndex-1].y - cy;

                //Angle Dragged Point
                a1 = Math.atan2(-y1,x1)*(180/Math.PI);

                //Mirrored Angle
                a2 = (a1-180)*(Math.PI/180)*(-1);

                //Mirrored Point Radius
                r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2, 2)+Math.pow(y2, 2));

                //Apply new Position to Point
                point.cp[draggedItemIndex-1].x = cx + r * Math.cos(a2);
                point.cp[draggedItemIndex-1].y = cy + r * Math.sin(a2);
```